# How to implement a flyweight pattern with overridable properties?

Tags: design-patterns

I want to implement a system of components that are shared between multiple nodes of a tree.
I imagined the Flyweight pattern is really good for this use.
The component is instantiated only once and this instance is given to each node that needs it.
This way, if a property of the component changes, it is immediately shared to the nodes.

Now, I want to change just one single parameter of a component on a node without affecting the other nodes.
But I don't want to copy the instance of the component in order to do that.

- If the property is changed at a component-level, the new value will be shared to the nodes, unless this property was explicitly changed on the node.
- If the property is changed at a node-level, it overrides the one from the component.

What I want to create is a mechanism similar to the scene tree in Unity were we can override some properties of a component at node-level (for example, when we use prefabs) without affecting original resources unless we explicitly want to.

Now, I don't know how to make sort of a flyweight pattern with some kind of overridable properties.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Flyweight (as you clearly understand) uses shared objects, you cannot modify these objects without effecting everything pointing to that flyweight.  The way you solve this is to use composition.  That is, when you want to create an 'override' you create a new object that wraps the flyweight and applies the new behavior.  I'm a little rusty on my GoF patterns but I think this is essentially the Decorator pattern applied to Flyweights.

Comment: Good point! Do you think I should have one decorator for each property that is overridden (and potentially many decorations), or one decorator for all overridden properties?

Comment: It really depends on a lot of things.  Either are valid in my opinion.  It really depends on the context of what you are doing.  If you want to have each new override also shared as a flyweight, the one decorator would probably be the way to go.  There a lots of ways to go about this so I hesitate to prescribe a solution.  Try a few things and see what works is my best advice.  Generally, it will become obvious quickly if you took a wrong turn.